# How to calculate using some form field value and auto populate that calculated value in another django admin form?

Tags: python, django

I want to auto populate the calculated value in `rent_price` of `admin.py`:

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):  
    ...  
    mrp        = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places = 2)  
    rent_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places = 2)  
    ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    ...  
    prepopulated_fields = {'rent_price': ('calculated value based on mrp',),}  
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `prepopulated_fields` you can use [`get_prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_prepopulated_fields)

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    ...  
    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        prepopulated_fields = self.prepopulated_fields
        if obj:
            prepopulated_fields.update({
                'rent_price': get_rent_price_from_mrp(obj.mrp)
            })
        return prepopulated_fields
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help.. I want little more clear answer.. When admin is uploading a 'Book' in django admin panel, suppose 'mrp' is 100 so 'rent_price' is 25% of mrp i.e, 25. I want the value 25 which is calculated based on 'mrp' to be auto_populate after admin fill the 'mrp' field.

Comment: @Muhammad_Tahir thanks for this answer, helped in my issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pre_save signals (this is what you need judging from your comment on Muhammads answer).
When you create your Book in the admin, just before saving django will call your pre_save method for the book model and calculate the rent_price based on the mrp you submitted in your admin form.
You may have to alter the model for the rent allowing it to be null if the validation for the form submission fails, or deal with the validation another way.

This is a decent tutorial on signals: http://www.koopman.me/2015/01/django-signals-example/ which includes a link to the django docs.

But beware, signals are not triggered on bulk methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple answer based on @Muhammad_Tahir answer:

in your admin define a function:

```
def get_discount_rate(self, obj=None):
    mrp = ((obj.rent_price/obj.mrp)*100)
    return mrp
```

then inside your admin registration class, add following function:

```
@admin.register(ModelToRegister)
class ModelToRegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    prepopulated_fields = {}

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        prepopulated_fields = self.prepopulated_fields
        if obj:
            prepopulated_fields.update({
                'mrp': get_discount_rate(obj=obj)
            })
        return prepopulated_fields
```